# WPF - Passing dependencies between windows

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have Login window and a Home window, inside the login class the Home is opened and the Login is closed:

```
Home home = new Home(user, _gitApiService);
home.Show();
Close();
```

Because the Home class relies on a dependency of IGitApiService, I am passing the dependency via the window class's constructor:

```
public partial class Home : Window
{
    private readonly IGitApiService _gitApiService;

    public Home(User user, IGitApiService gitApiService)
    {
         _gitApiService = gitApiService;
```

...etc

This seems like bad practice to me, is there any cleaner way of accessing/instaniating the IGitApiService?

(For context the GitApiService is just a class with api calls using HttpClient)

Comment: Are you using a DI/IoC Container? Does the Login window also depend on that  `IGitApiService` service?

Comment: The login window does also depend on the same service. I'm currently registering the interfaces in a configure services method in my App.xaml.cs file like so... ```services.AddHttpClient<IGitApiService, GitApiService>(```...etc

Comment: the configure services method also registers the Login as transient i.e. ```services.AddTransient(typeof(Login));```I am also running ```var login = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Login>();``` from my startup method.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there are only a few dependencies then such [poor man's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364090/is-poor-mans-dependency-injection-a-good-way-to-introduce-testability-to-a-lega)/[pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) isn't something really bad.

But if it is a common scenario and there are many dependencies, then by all means register a factory for the Home page (as `user` seems to be some domain object that can't be registered in CompositionRoot):

```
 services.Register<Func<User, Home>>(context => 
     user => new Home(user, context.Resolve<IGitApiService>());
```

or however explicitly or implicitly it is done in the DI framework used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Slight design change to `Home` window

```
public partial class Home : Window {
    private readonly IGitApiService _gitApiService;

    public Home(IGitApiService gitApiService) {
         _gitApiService = gitApiService;
    }

    public User User { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

I would have a window service responsible for showing a desired window

```
public interface IWindowService {
    public void Show<TWindow>(Action<TWindow> configure = null) where TWindow : Window;
}

public class WindowService : IWindowService {
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public WindowService(IServiceProvider services) {
        this.services = services
    }

    public void Show<TWindow>(Action<TWindow> configure = null) where TWindow : Window {
        var window = services.GetService<TWindow>();
        if(configure != null) {
            configure(window);
        }

        window.Show();
    }
}
```

With that in place you inject your window service and use it like

```
windowSevie.Show<Home>(window => window.User = user);
Close();
```

Any explicit dependencies are injected when the window is resolved, and the configure delegate allows flexibility to populate any other members as needed